# How can I figure out why a call to LLVMTargetMachineEmitToFile fails when called using llvm-sys?

Tags: rust, llvm

```
extern crate llvm_sys;

use llvm_sys::*;
use llvm_sys::prelude::*;
use llvm_sys::core::*;

pub fn emit(module: LLVMModuleRef) {
    unsafe {
        use llvm_sys::target::*;
        use llvm_sys::target_machine::*;
        let triple = LLVMGetDefaultTargetTriple();
        LLVM_InitializeNativeTarget();
        let target = LLVMGetFirstTarget();
        let cpu = "x86-64\0".as_ptr() as *const i8;
        let feature = "\0".as_ptr() as *const i8;
        let opt_level = LLVMCodeGenOptLevel::LLVMCodeGenLevelNone;
        let reloc_mode = LLVMRelocMode::LLVMRelocDefault;
        let code_model = LLVMCodeModel::LLVMCodeModelDefault;
        let target_machine = LLVMCreateTargetMachine(target, triple, cpu, feature, opt_level, reloc_mode, code_model);
        let file_type = LLVMCodeGenFileType::LLVMObjectFile;
        LLVMTargetMachineEmitToFile(target_machine, module, "/Users/andyshiue/Desktop/main.o\0".as_ptr() as *mut i8, file_type, ["Cannot generate file.\0".as_ptr()].as_mut_ptr() as *mut *mut i8);
    }
}
```

I'm writing a toy compiler and I want to generate object files, but the file LLVM outputs is empty.

I found that `LLVMTargetMachineEmitToFile` returns 1, which means something I'm doing is wrong, but what am I doing wrong?

It would be better if I can know how I can know what is wrong. Is there any way I can get some error message? I don't have any experience in C/C++.

Comment: Have you got it working in `C` first?

Comment: Do you mean C the programming language? I've not.

Comment: I suggest you read the API documents of LLVM, and sometimes the source for the meaning of the return results: http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/TargetMachineC_8cpp.html#ad9195990094524f9a0cfc80ef213e675  This may require some C/C++ knowledge.

Comment: Ok, I think reading C/C++ isn't a problem for me.

Comment: make sure your llvm is compiled with assertions, it will make your life much easier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As commenters have already said, to do what you want to do (write a compiler using LLVM), you are going to need to be able to read (and probably write) at the very least C and maybe C++.

Even though you are compiling code with the Rust compiler, you aren't really writing any Rust yet. Your *entire* program is wrapped in `unsafe` blocks because you are calling the C functions exposed by LLVM (which is written in C++). This may be why some commenters are asking if you have gotten your code to work in C first.

As in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37256726/155423), you are still calling the LLVM methods incorrectly. In this case, review [the documentation for `LLVMTargetMachineEmitToFile`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/TargetMachineC_8cpp.html#ad9195990094524f9a0cfc80ef213e675):

> ```
> LLVMBool LLVMTargetMachineEmitToFile(LLVMTargetMachineRef T,
>                                      LLVMModuleRef M,
>                                      char *Filename,
>                                      LLVMCodeGenFileType codegen,
>                                      char **ErrorMessage)
> ```
>
> Returns any error in ErrorMessage. Use LLVMDisposeMessage to dispose the message.

The method itself will tell you what is wrong, but you have to give it a place to store the error message. You should **not** provide an error string to it. I'm pretty sure that the current code is likely to generate some exciting memory errors when it tries to write to the string literal.

If I rewrite your code to use the error message:

```
extern crate llvm_sys;

use llvm_sys::*;
use llvm_sys::prelude::*;
use llvm_sys::core::*;

use std::ptr;
use std::ffi::{CStr, CString};

pub fn emit(module: LLVMModuleRef) {
    let cpu = CString::new("x86-64").expect("invalid cpu");
    let feature = CString::new("").expect("invalid feature");
    let output_file = CString::new("/tmp/output.o").expect("invalid file");

    unsafe {
        use llvm_sys::target::*;
        use llvm_sys::target_machine::*;
        let triple = LLVMGetDefaultTargetTriple();
        LLVM_InitializeNativeTarget();
        let target = LLVMGetFirstTarget();
        let opt_level = LLVMCodeGenOptLevel::LLVMCodeGenLevelNone;
        let reloc_mode = LLVMRelocMode::LLVMRelocDefault;
        let code_model = LLVMCodeModel::LLVMCodeModelDefault;
        let target_machine = LLVMCreateTargetMachine(target, triple, cpu.as_ptr(), feature.as_ptr(), opt_level, reloc_mode, code_model);
        let file_type = LLVMCodeGenFileType::LLVMObjectFile;

        let mut error_str = ptr::null_mut();
        let res = LLVMTargetMachineEmitToFile(target_machine, module, output_file.as_ptr() as *mut i8, file_type, &mut error_str);
        if res == 1 {
            let x = CStr::from_ptr(error_str);
            panic!("It failed! {:?}", x);
            // TODO: Use LLVMDisposeMessage here
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        let module = LLVMModuleCreateWithName("Main\0".as_ptr() as *const i8);
        emit(module);
    }
}
```

> TargetMachine can't emit a file of this type

So that's your problem.

Rust-wise, you may want to wrap up the work needed to handle the silly `LLVMBool` so you can reuse it. One way would be:

```
fn llvm_bool<F>(f: F) -> Result<(), String>
    where F: FnOnce(&mut *mut i8) -> i32
{
    let mut error_str = ptr::null_mut();
    let res = f(&mut error_str);
    if res == 1 {
        let err = unsafe { CStr::from_ptr(error_str) };
        Err(err.to_string_lossy().into_owned())
        //LLVMDisposeMessage(error_str);
    } else {
        Ok(())
    }
}

// later

llvm_bool(|error_str| LLVMTargetMachineEmitToFile(target_machine, module, output_file.as_ptr() as *mut i8, file_type, error_str)).expect("Couldn't output");
```